# How to forbid access to all directories except one using web.config in IIS8?

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, yii2, web-config

I developed a web project based on Yii2, so it's necesarry to forbid access to all file and directory except the sub-directory "web".

Below is project directory struct:

> ```
> .htaccess
> composer.json
> config/
>     console.php
>     web.php
> commands/
> controllers/
> models/
> runtime/
> vendor/
> views/
> web/
>     .htaccess   
>     assets/         
>     index.php
> ```

I have achieved this under apache by .htaccess, it's very very easy ^_^

.htaccess

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
```

web/.htaccess

```
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from All
```

But I need to deploy this project under IIS8 now, so I tried to convert .htaccess to web.config using IIS management, but convert result is empty.
How can I do this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

IIS uses the Request Filtering module to limit browser access to files that are components of the application. For the sample application in a Web.config file, the section could look like:

```
<security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <denyUrlSequences>
                <add sequence="engine" />
                <add sequence="inc" />
                <add sequence="info" />
                <add sequence="install" />
                <add sequence="module" />
                <add sequence="profile" />
                <add sequence="po" />
                <add sequence="sh" />
                <add sequence="theme" />
                <add sequence="tpl(\.php" />
                <add sequence="Root" />
                <add sequence="Tag" />
                <add sequence="Template" />
                <add sequence="Repository" />
                <add sequence="code-style" />
            </denyUrlSequences>
            <fileExtensions>
                <add fileExtension=".sql" allowed="false" />
                <add fileExtension=".pl" allowed="false" />
            </fileExtensions>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

Note that you can leave this section commented out for installation, because the installation scripts are blocked by this filter.

An alternative to using the request filtering is to use the URL Rewriter module to return a 403 error for any of the matching file types. The advantage of the URL Rewriter module is that it uses a regular expression for the match.

```
        <rule name="Protect files and directories from prying eyes" stopProcessing="true"> 
            <match url="\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$" /> 
            <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="403" subStatusCode="0" 
                statusReason="Forbidden" 
                statusDescription="Access is forbidden." /> 
        </rule>
```

Comment: My purpose is to forbid directory access (include all sub-directories and files in sub-directories), not to limit directory index.

Comment: It will deny access to folders and subfolders, it will throw 403 Exception when someone try to access it.

Comment: It can't forbid access to file. For example, www.example.com/web/config.php